# Unsure about how to test for convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3e^{-n^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm struggling with figuring out if the series below converges

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3e^{-n^3}$$

I know that if it was $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2e^{-n^3}$$

one can just us the integral test as the substitution for $n^2$ makes the integral easy to solve.

However, I'm unsure about how to go about it in the above scenario.

Any answers will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Compare with $\sum e^{-n}$.

Comment: Understand exponential growth compared to polynomials. What about $\sum n^8 e^{-n}$?

Comment: Root test is also your friend.

Comment: Eventually $e^{n^3}\ge n^5 \iff e^{-n^3}\le \frac1{n^5}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Lemma.** For any positive integer $n$ and positive number $x$,
$$
\mathrm{e}^{x} > \frac{x^n}{n!}.
$$

**Proof.** Define, for any real number $x$,
$$
f(x) = \frac{1 + x + x^2/2 + \dots + x^n/n!}{\mathrm{e}^{x}}.
$$
It is not hard to see that $f(0) = 1$, and
$$
f'(x) = -\frac{x^n}{n!} \mathrm{e}^{-x} < 0
$$
for $x > 0$. Hence $f$ is decreasing on $[0, \infty)$.

---

**A hint for your question.** Note that for any $x > 0$,
$$
\frac{x}{\mathrm{e}^{x}} 
< \frac{x}{x^3/6}
= \frac{6}{x^2}.
$$
Hence
$$
0 < n^3 \mathrm{e}^{-n^3} < \frac{6}{n^6}.
$$
You should be able to solve your question by appealing to the comparison test.

Comment: Also follows from the power series.

Comment: @martycohen Yes. I believe that that is more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Simply [d'Alembert's ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) will do the job or the [Cauchy root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test): $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^3}{e^{-n^{3}}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}\sqrt[n]{n}\sqrt[n]{n}}{e^{-n^2}}=0\le 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

The [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) still works here.

Let $f(x)=x^3e^{-x^3}$. Now $f$ is strictly positive for $x>0$ so with the change of variables $t=x^3$,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_1^{+\infty} x^3e^{-x^3}\ dx<\int_0^{+\infty} x^3e^{-x^3}\ dx&=\frac{1}{3}\overbrace{\int_0^{+\infty} t^{1/3}e^{-t}\ dt}^{\Gamma(4/3)}
\end{align*}$$
we see that the integral is in fact convergent and the respective sum,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3e^{-n^3}$$
also converges by the integral test.

---

More generally for $f(x)=x^ae^{-x^a}$,
$$\int_0^{+\infty} x^{a}e^{-x^a}\ dx=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{+\infty} t^{1/a} e^{-t}\ dt=\frac{1}{a}\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)$$
converges for $a>0$ and its respective sum,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^ae^{-n^a}$$
also converges in the same region.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can judge, the following integral converges for every $a>=1$:

$$\int{x^a e^{-x^a} dx}$$

The convergence of your sum is just a consequence of this.